# Autocomplete Field in View Exposed Filter

Tags: views, taxonomy-terms, ajax

I have created an index Using the Search Api. and integrate with View. And in filter criteria
i have indexed vocabulary. then i want to expose that filter criteria with auto complete field 
instead of select list.

Answer (score 1):

I think you created a **indexed view** in which the dropdown option will not appear in filters. you can alter the form by the following steps

> Alter the type of the field as text
>
> Provide a ajax callback for that field by creating a menu. I provide you with a sample code for it :)

eg:  `$form['location']['#autocomplete_path'] = 'location_autocomplete';`

**Sample Code** :

```
function mymodule_menu() {
     $items = array();
      $items['location_autocomplete'] = array(
    'page callback' => 'location_autocomplete_callback',
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK,
    'access arguments' => array('access content'),
  );
}

function location_autocomplete_callback($string = "") {
  $matches = array();
  // apply sql queries to get the field values
  drupal_json_output($matches);
}
```